Scilab Hierarchical Cluster Analysis
On Scilab 5.5.2 I have carried out some Hierarchical Cluster Analysis using the IPT3 toolbox, an example is shown below:
clear;
sheets=readxls(uigetfile("*.xls"));
data=sheets(1).value;
datascaled=center(data,"r");
D="euclidean";
L="ward";
Y=pdist(datascaled,D);
Z=linkage(Y,L);
H=dendrogram(Z,0);
gcf().figure_size=[1206,731];
xtitle("Dendrogram (center, "+L+")","","Distance ("+D+")");

Those calculations, i. e. plotting a dendrogram, can be done also without the IPT3 toolbox but with another toolbox and without coding starting from zero?
